# How to get Git logs done by members

Tags: git, github

How do I get the list of `"git pull"` done by the members of repository> I have a repo, I wanted to know when was the last time "git pull" has been done by a member.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization. But it seems available for enterprise repos only.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide a way to view logs of when people pull from the repository. They receive many requests in a day, many of which are anonymous, and providing this data wouldn't be very performant. There are also privacy concerns with providing some of this data, especially if it included anonymous users or users from outside your organization.

The audit log contains some user-relevant information, but fetches and pulls are not included. Usually events included here are things like password changes and other potentially security-sensitive events.

If you want to see a history of pushes, you can do that with a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). The difference is the scale: there are many, many fetch requests for each push that occurs.